# What exactly is parameter containing with ref modifier?

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, ref

I want to ask something about ref modifier.

**What I know and understand:**
With method that use ref modifier, there will be no copy of data as with passing by value, but parameter will have directly access to argument value. Basically said, all you done in method’s scope will act same as if you would done it with argument (passed variable) in caller’s scope.

and **I want to ask what is exactly stored in parameter with ref modifier:**
When I pass argument to method with ref modifier, will parameter contain reference to value of argument? or is it something else?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: A 'ref' parameter contains a reference to pointer in memory, where actual value is stored.

Comment: Might want to check out Microsoft's [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) on the `ref` keyword

Comment: https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/chap8_9781509301041/elementLinks/08fig01.jpg

Comment: `ref` is *horribly* misunderstood by a lot of people; I don't know it it will help, but I tried to discuss it by comparing to C/C++ pointers here: http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/04/spans-and-ref-part-1-ref.html

Comment: The two answers are good, but its important to understand that the ref keyword is only meaningful for value types, reference types work that way without it. Its important to know that strings are a reference type, which is one of the few basic types that are. Also structs are value types.......

http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a parameter with the `ref` attribute, it passes the argument by reference and not value.  That means a new copy of the variable is not being made, rather a pointer to the original is being used within your function.

```
public void Foo()
    {
        var x = 0;
        Bar(x); // x still equals 0
        Bar(ref x); // x now equals 1
    }

    public void Bar(ref int x)
    {
        x = 1;
    }

    public void Bar(int x)
    {
        x = 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have this method:

```
public void DoSomething(int number)
{
    number = 20;
}
```

And we use it:

```
var number = 10;
DoSomething(number);
Console.WriteLine("Our number is: {0}", number);
```

The output would be `Our number is: 10`. Our number does not become 20.

That's because we're **passing by value**, so we're basically taking a copy of `number` before we change it.

However, if we **pass by reference** instead:

```
public void DoSomething(ref int number)
{
    number = 20;
}
```

And then use our method:

```
var number = 10;
DoSomething(ref number);
Console.WriteLine("Our number is: {0}", number);
```

The output then becomes `Our number is: 20`